# how to _gat.anonymizeIp when using multiple trackers

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using asynchronous google analytics tracking in my web-app. The google analytics JS code is also integrated into third-party web-pages. I need to track visitors on the the third-party websites seperately to my own website. That's why I am using multiple trackers, as below.

I need to anonymize the IP for my tracking. But I don't want to affect the tracking on the third-party websites. I am attempting to achieve this with the code below.

```
// create a tracker for use on my own web-site
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['myWebSiteTracker._setAccount', 'UA-65432-1']);
_gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);
_gaq.push(['myWebSiteTracker._trackPageview']);

// In the same webpage that the code above is running, the 3rd-party 
// webpage could idself create a tracker using...
_gaq.push(['thirdPartyTracker._setAccount', 'UA-65432-2']);
_gaq.push(['thirdPartyTracker._trackPageview']);
```

However, with the code above, every tracking event that is called after pushing `_gat._anonymizeIp` will have the IP anonymized, but I only want events recorded on the `myWebsiteTracker` tracker to be anonymized, is this possible?

Comment: Use "_gaq.push(['myWebSiteTracker._gat._anonymizeIp']);" before calling "_gaq.push(['myWebSiteTracker._trackPageview']);" instead of the global "_gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);".

Answer (score 1):

AnonymizeIp affects everything, it's not a per-tracker configuration. But what you can do is change the order so it's not in effect when the `thirdPartyTracker` fires.

```
// In the same webpage that the code above is running, the 3rd-party 
// webpage could idself create a tracker using...
_gaq.push(['thirdPartyTracker._setAccount', 'UA-65432-2']);
_gaq.push(['thirdPartyTracker._trackPageview']);

// create a tracker for use on my own web-site
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['myWebSiteTracker._setAccount', 'UA-65432-1']);
_gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);
_gaq.push(['myWebSiteTracker._trackPageview']);
```